# What is the probability that failure will be by each of these three mechanisms?

Tags: probability

**Question:** A certain type of electric motor fails either by seizure of the bearings, or by
burning out of the electric windings, or by wearing out of the brushes. Suppose that
seizure is twice as likely as burning out, which is four times as likely as brush wearout.
What is the probability that failure will be by each of these three mechanisms?

**My solution =**

Probability of seizure of the bearings $= P(S)$

Probability of burning out of the electric windings $= P(E)$

Probability of wearing out of the brushes $= P(W)$

$$P(S) = P(E)/2$$

$$P(E) = P(W)/4$$

$$P(S) + P(E) + P(W) = 1$$

$$P(E)/2 + P(E) + 4P(E) = 1$$

....

And then I solve for $P(S)$, $P(E)$ and $P(W)$

However, I'm obviously going wrong somewhere as I'm not getting the correct answer. Any help would be much appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: You want $P(S) = 2P(E)$, it's twice as likely, not half as likely. The wording is a bit ambiguous, I'm not sure if they mean $2P(E) = 4P(W)$ or $P(E) = 4P(W)$ but you can ask for clarification or just test both.

Comment: You are assuming that the events are independent and that they sum up to 1.

Comment: Apologies, I should have added the answers: 1/13, 4/13 and 8/13 which means they meant P(E) = 4P(W)

Comment: Thank you, I solved it. The most obvious errors can be the ones that are most difficult to spot! Cheers again.